# URL rewriting with Wordpress Rewrite or .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to append to wordpress an additional parameter into my URL.
For example, I have the URL: http://example.com 
I want to change that to URL: http://example.com/this-example/

I'm thinking I can do this is in htaccess along the lines of a rewrite condition, but i'm unsure how to go about this. This is what I was thinking here.

**Htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/this-example/(.*)/ /index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: is this supposed to be routed through wordpress as well or an independent URL? Do you just want to use wordpress in a subdirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/this-example [NC]
    # use your own host here, for me is 192.68.10.10
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 192\.168\.10\.10$ [NC] 
    RewriteRule !^this-example/ /this-example%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,NE]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^this-example/(.*)$ $1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: thank you! I ended up resolving it without having to do a mod_rewrite. But honestly this was so useful.